# Can't install Django in visual studio code

Tags: python, django, web, backend

So I'm creating a forum according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXmsi13cMhw&t=2594s

I'm stuck at 2:10.I've successfully created a virtual enviroment, can't go past this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JTbO.png)

Where do I get project name?What on Earth is wrong here?Sorry if I got a little emotional.

I tried to do everything exactly like in aforementioned tutorial.

Comment: I don't know AutoDjango, but I think you misspelled `--post-installation` with an underscore.

Comment: "-- django" should be "--django" with no space as well.

Comment: python AutoDjango/AutoDjango.py --django --project project --app main --post_installation doesn't work. Says unrecognized arguments: post_installation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

python AutoDjango.py --django --project PROJECTNAME --app APPNAME solved it.
In the tutorial,for some reason, he used post_installation command assuming we are doind for the first time. and didnt clarify it. No offence though.
So, deleting post_installation solved it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).